# How to use multiple functions, with equations, in a scope using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
myApp.controller('incomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.pay = 0;
  $scope.hours = 0;
     $scope.tax=0.19297;
    
    $scope.total = function() {
    return $scope.pay * $scope.hours;}


    
        $scope.taxTotal = function ($scope){
          return($scope.total * $scope.tax);}
        


            $scope.afterTaxTotal = function ($scope){
                return($scope.total - $scope.taxTotal);}

  

 }]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="incomeController">
  <h2>Income Calculator</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
  
    <p16>Pay Rate: </p16><input type="number" ng-model="pay"> 
   <p15> Hours worked:</p15> <input type="number" ng-model="hours">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


     <p><b>Total Before Taxes:</b> {{ total() | currency : $ }}</p>
    
    
    </div>

    <p><b>Total Taxes :</b> {{ taxTotal() | currency : $ }}</p>



<p><b>Total After Taxes:</b> {{ afterTaxTotal() | currency : $ }}</p>
```

I am trying to do a simple algebra equation.

1. have the user input two numbers
2. multiply them together
3. multiply the answer (step 2) to an already assigned variable
4. subtract the answer in step 2 from step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your functions with the parenthesis inside the controller as well.

```
      function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.pay = 5;
        $scope.hours = 10;
        $scope.tax= 0.19297;

        $scope.total = function() { 
          return $scope.pay * $scope.hours;
         };

        $scope.taxTotal = function () { 
         return $scope.total() * $scope.tax;
        };

        $scope.afterTaxTotal = function () { 
            return $scope.total() - $scope.taxTotal();
        };


      }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m62f70mk/5/

Also, you dont need to pass $scope, it is available inside your functions. And what is going on with your paragraph tags? ?